# Совет по использованию элементов в верстке в Android

Tags: android

Пишу расписание. Хочу создать фрагмент с параметрами поиска расписания.

Имеется параметры группа, курс, семестр.

Остальные параметры будут зависеть от выбранного типа расписания : на конкретное число, на неделю, за семестр

В зависимости от типа расписания добавляются дополнительное поле:

```
на конкретное число - будет выбор через календарь
на неделю - выбор через календарь (выбирается дата, а по нему будет определяться учебная неделя и рядом просто spinner с выбором недели)
на семестр - тогда ничего не будет добавляться
```

Вот эту разную часть я хочу реализовать в одном месте.
Варианты:

1. Использовать ViewPager (Но я думаю там нельзя как то засунуть общие параметры выше viewPager)

   2. Менять во FrameLayout фрагменты (от типа) по нажатию на checkBox
   3. Вообще полностью разные фрагменты.

Посоветуйте как реализовать. Хотелось бы чтобы переключение разной части было наподобии работы ViewPager, но думаю так нельзя реализовать

Comment: Код мы будем за вас писать?

Comment: @And Возможно я не так выразился, я хотел спросить не как реализовать (не прошу кода), а как лучше реализовать в соответствии более удобного пользовательского взаимодействия (или какого-либо gideline)

Comment: вы можете реализовать общие для трех вариантов пункты на одной разметке , а в этой же разметке под ними вьюпейджер с различающимися пунктами. пейджер не обязательно должен занимать весь экран, может и какую то часть только